# How to tile a texture with displacement without repetition

Tags: pbr

I'm trying to lear how to texture a scene so I [downloaded a texture](https://polyhaven.com/a/white_rough_plaster) and I applied onto the walls of my scene.

It looks great but you can clearly see repetition on the wall with the doorway which isn't nice. And on the side walls you clearly see that it requires to be scale it up.

I found plenty of tutorial in how to tile a texture without repetition but it does not apply for texture with displacement. And I can't found any guidelines on how to properly do that  **with displacement**.

Do you have any clue on how to repeat a texture with displacement ?

My scene :

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: you mean you've used the Displacement node? If you have found the way to avoid repetition, what was the method and why can't you use the same method with this node?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.